# Compress range of values

Tags: sql, oracle, range

I have a data base with date of sale, name of good, place of sale and good's id.
My task is to compress the data. For example, from

```
(15.02.2020, ff, rt, 5)
(15.02.2020, ff, rt, 6)
(15.02.2020, ff, rt, 7)
(15.02.2020, ss, rt, 8)
(15.02.2020, ss, rt, 9)
```

I need to get

```
(15.02.2020, ff, rt, 5, 7, 3)
(15.02.2020, ss, rt, 8, 9, 2)
```

My code is

```
select 
    date, 
    name, 
    place, 
    min(id) over partition by (date, name, place) as id_start, 
    max(id) over partition by (date, name, place) as id_end, 
    max(id) over partition by (date, name, place) - min(id) over partition by (date, name, place) as count 
from t
```

However, problem with min/max partition is that if I have data like `(15.02.2020, ss, rt, 9)` and `(15.02.2020, ss, rt, 55)` my script gives me `(15.02.2020, ss, rt, 9, 55, 47)` so 47 goods were sold when in real life only 2 goods were sold.

I suppose, I'd better do this with `lead(id) partition by (date, name, place) order by (id)` however I don't understand how I can count in this case.

I would appriciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like an ordinary `count` with `listagg` (line #20, `id_sold`). If you want to display only min and max `ID`s, fetch them and concatenate their values (line #21, `id_sold_2`):

Sample data:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     test (datum,
  3           name,
  4           place,
  5           id)
  6     AS
  7        (SELECT DATE '2020-02-15', 'ff', 'rt', 5 FROM DUAL
  8         UNION ALL
  9         SELECT DATE '2020-02-15', 'ff', 'rt', 6 FROM DUAL
 10         UNION ALL
 11         SELECT DATE '2020-02-15', 'ff', 'rt', 7 FROM DUAL
 12         UNION ALL
 13         --
 14         SELECT DATE '2020-02-15', 'ss', 'rt', 8 FROM DUAL
 15         UNION ALL
 16         SELECT DATE '2020-02-15', 'ss', 'rt', 9 FROM DUAL)
```

Query begins here:

```
 17    SELECT datum,
 18           name,
 19           place,
 20           LISTAGG (id, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) id_sold,
 21           MIN (id) || ', ' || MAX (id) id_sold_2,
 22           COUNT (*) number_sold
 23      FROM test
 24  GROUP BY datum, name, place;

DATUM      NAME PLACE ID_SOLD         ID_SOLD_2       NUMBER_SOLD
---------- ---- ----- --------------- --------------- -----------
15.02.2020 ff   rt    5, 6, 7         5, 7                      3
15.02.2020 ss   rt    8, 9            8, 9                      2

SQL>
```

Comment: but the problem with min/max remains, there are gaps in data. So in cases ('2020-02-15', 'ff', 'rt', 51), ('2020-02-15', 'ff', 'rt', 52) and ('2020-02-15', 'ff', 'rt', 147) I want to get ('2020-02-15', 'ff', 'rt', 51, 52, 2) and ('2020-02-15', 'ff', 'rt', 147, 147, 1) but min/max will give me ('2020-02-15', 'ff', 'rt', 51, 147, 3)
somehow I need to check if id difference is > 1 then it is different count and different 'block' of data